# Derivative of f(x) from Graph

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

How to obtain the derivative of a function from this graph? Also, where $f'(x)$ is not defined?

[image]

I noticed that points $1$, $4$ and $0$ is where the graph has a corner (is this correct?). Any other points where it is not differentiable?

Also, about the derivative of the graph, any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, at those corner points $f$ is not differentiable. And rest of the graphs are different straight lines. Try to find the slopes of the lines.

Comment: @AvisekSharma, How about identifyinng the function f(x) or its derivative function from graph? Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is right for the interior points and note that we also need to include the boundary points $x=-4$ and $x=6$ among those where $f'(x)$ is not defined, if these are included in the domain for $f(x)$.

For the graph of the derivative we exclude the corner and boudary points and evaluate f'(x) in between, which is a contant value for each interval, according to

$$f'(x)=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\quad x_1 <x<x_2 $$

Comment: How about the derivative graph of such a function. Any shortcuts to identify the function from the graph?

Comment: @Aruha I've added something on that point.

Comment: I accept the answer. Thanks a million. Great help. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Aruha You are welcome. You could also add your final result editing your answer if you like in order to have a full solution given. Bye